# Create a range of decimal number using numpy does not work

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I want to create a range of values between 521 and 522 with step 0.1. This is my code:

```
ICD9CD1 = np.arange(521, 522, 0.1)
```

The result is:

```
array([521. , 521.1, 521.2, 521.3, 521.4, 521.5, 521.6, 521.7, 521.8,
       521.9])
```

but when I want to covert it to a list, this is the result:

```
np.arange(521, 522, 0.1).tolist()

[521.0,
 521.1,
 521.2,
 521.3000000000001,
 521.4000000000001,
 521.5000000000001,
 521.6000000000001,
 521.7000000000002,
 521.8000000000002,
 521.9000000000002]
```

What part of my code is wrong? I want this list as my output:
[521. , 521.1, 521.2, 521.3, 521.4, 521.5, 521.6, 521.7, 521.8,
           521.9]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either use `np.arange(5210, 5220) / 10` or `np.linspace(521, 522, 10, endpoint=False)`, but read the whole answer.

---

Part of your code *is* wrong, but not the way you're thinking.

Floating-point operations have rounding error. This is fundamental to floating point, and a fundamental limitation of trying to perform real-number computations on computers with finite resources. Even symbolic computation won't fix things - when an expression can't be symbolically simplified, you end up just building giant expression trees instead of actually computing anything.

The mere presence of rounding error in your output doesn't mean you've done something wrong. Also, the rounding error was already present in the `arange` output, just hidden by NumPy's default print settings - it wasn't introduced in the `tolist` call. For any even slightly nontrivial floating point calculation, you'll never eliminate all rounding error.

Even a result that looks like `[521. , 521.1, 521.2, 521.3, 521.4, 521.5, 521.6, 521.7, 521.8, 521.9]` would actually have rounding error, because the real number 521.1 is not actually representable in binary floating point. Most numbers that look like they're in that list aren't representable in binary floating point. The (64-bit) float `521.1` is actually `521.1000000000000227373675443232059478759765625`, but most programming languages don't display the exact value by default.

---

The part of your code that really is wrong is the use of `arange` with floating-point inputs. `arange` is inconsistent with floating-point inputs, because based on rounding error, it may have more or less elements than expected. For example,

```
np.arange(1, 1.3, 0.1)
```

returns

```
array([1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3])
```

rather than

```
array([1. , 1.1, 1.2])
```

because of floating-point rounding error in the computation of the length of the result.

Also, due to some weird implementation decisions, `arange` with floating-point inputs has a lot more rounding error than it should even when it gets the right output size.

`np.linspace` is designed to avoid the problems with `arange`. It takes the output size as an argument directly, instead of computing it from the step, and has an explicit parameter for whether or not to include the right endpoint. This avoids rounding error in the output size computation, as long as you don't introduce it yourself by computing the output size in floating point. `np.linspace` also has less rounding error than `arange` in the computation of the output elements. It is not guaranteed to have the least rounding error possible - for example, `np.linspace(0, 3, 148)[::49].tolist()` shows excess rounding error - but it does a lot better than floating-point `arange`.

`np.arange(5210, 5220) / 10` uses `arange` with integer arguments and divides afterward. This option has only one source of rounding error, the division by 10. This division is guaranteed by the IEEE 754 spec to be *correctly rounded*, in that the results will be rounded to the floating-point values closest to the ideal real-number results of the division. This option guarantees the least rounding error, beating `linspace` in some cases. For example, `np.arange(148) / 49` beats `np.linspace(0, 3, 148)` in rounding error.

Answer (score 2):

`arange` docs warns:

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not
>   be consistent.  It is better to use `numpy.linspace` for these cases.

What you see is a combination of floating point imprecision, and the `arange` way of generating successive values.  Floating point values are never exact.

`arange` recommends using `linspace` with fractional steps.  Just be careful to choose the right number:

```
In [301]: np.linspace(521,522,11)                                                                                    
Out[301]: 
array([521. , 521.1, 521.2, 521.3, 521.4, 521.5, 521.6, 521.7, 521.8,
       521.9, 522. ])
In [302]: np.linspace(521,522,11).tolist()                                                                           
Out[302]: [521.0, 521.1, 521.2, 521.3, 521.4, 521.5, 521.6, 521.7, 521.8, 521.9, 522.0]
```

Generating integer values, and scaling them also works:

```
In [303]: (np.arange(5210,5220)/10)                                                                                  
Out[303]: 
array([521. , 521.1, 521.2, 521.3, 521.4, 521.5, 521.6, 521.7, 521.8,
       521.9])
In [304]: (np.arange(5210,5220)/10).tolist()                                                                         
Out[304]: [521.0, 521.1, 521.2, 521.3, 521.4, 521.5, 521.6, 521.7, 521.8, 521.9]
```

this can also be done with python's `range`:

```
In [305]: [i/10 for i in range(5210,5220)]                                                                           
Out[305]: [521.0, 521.1, 521.2, 521.3, 521.4, 521.5, 521.6, 521.7, 521.8, 521.9]
```

Comment: I think you meant the `arange` docs, not the `argparse` docs.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, yes.  I was thinking about another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
list(np.around(np.arange(521, 522, 0.1),2))
```